# How to Facebook share a single blog post, rather than the entire blog feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I'm hoping my question isn't stupid, I'm very new with Javascript.

I've created a Facebook share button by using a script directly from Facebook:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

However, when I click the link, it wants to share the entire URL of my blog, rather than just the specific blog post. I have read other people suggesting something about Open Graph, but am unsure how this relates. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to replace `location.href` with that blog post's specific URL.

If you use Wordpress, you can add into [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(<?php the_permalink(); ?>), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```

In Wordpress, `the_permalink()` will return the exact URL for that post, ensuring that Facebook will only share that specific post.

Comment: Thanks for the tip shshaw! I'm using SquareSpace, and I'm doing some research as to target a blog's specific permalink. Some people suggest href="http://mydomain.com{permalink}", but that's not working.

Comment: I actually figured it out! For SquareSpace, you need to just simply place {permalink} after the equal sign. :)

Comment: Great! Glad you found it. If SquareSpace allows, you may want to do this:
`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('{permalink}'), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;">Share on Facebook</a>`

The `encodeURIComponent` part formats the permalink in a way that won't cause any issues with special characters, spacing, etc. when sending the URL to Facebook.